# How do I configure CORS globally in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors

I am trying to configure CORS globally in Spring using the following code:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(false);
    }
}
```

However, I am being blocked when I make a call from *http://localhost:3000*

Message:

*'Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8081/api/assignments' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.'*

Any suggestion would be great. Thanks.

Comment: *I am being blocked* [...] What error message do you get? That's essential information for a good question about a CORS issue.

Comment: You should also add HEAD and OPTIONS to the allowed methods. The pre-flight request is generally one of those.

Comment: @M.Deinum No. Preflight requests always use the `OPTIONS` method, but because they're automatically sent by the browser, the `OPTIONS` method never needs to be allowed by the server's CORS config for preflight to succeed.

Answer (score -1):

This is what resolved my CORS issue:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig
{
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer()
    {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And an important step if you are using Spring security is the following:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
            .and()......
```